# Is it possible to convert a PC (Windows 10) to a DLNA device?

Tags: windows-10, android, dlna

My phone has the capability to connect and "throw" contents to a DLNA device. Now I'm looking for a way to make it so that my computer is detected as DLNA device (aka, something I can "throw" things to). All the tutorials I see are how to make the PC a DLNA media server which is **not** what I want.

Comment: Windows Media Player on Windows 10 already has this capability built-in

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could go for free third-party DLNA Media renderers,
for example [Kodi](https://kodi.tv) (or [DIVX](http://www.divx.com/en/software/technologies/dlna)) which I use for this purpose. 
As stated in the [Official Kodi Wiki](https://kodi.wiki/view/Archive:UPnP/Client) (slightly edited),

> Kodi UPnP client (aka UPnP renderer) allows Kodi to instantly playback and control videos and music sent to it from a UPnP server and control point. …
>
> To turn on Kodi's UPnP client, in Kodi go to "Settings" -> "Services" -> "UPnP" and enable "Allow control of Kodi via UPnP".

Also: Remember to allow Kodi in firewall settings.

Screenshots:

[image]

Kodi media renderer (Note Kodi can act as both DNLA media server/renderer.)

[image]

Android DLNA app accessing Kodi player

Ref: [UPnP/Client – Official Kodi Wiki](https://kodi.wiki/view/Archive:UPnP/Client).

Comment: I have enabled the setting on Kodi but my phone still doesn't find my PC. Is there any other thing I need to set up?

Comment: Sorry for late response, if everything is set and still you cant access your PC player, its most likely firewall is blocking connection, please activate Kodi in firewall settings

Answer (score 2):

Yes – what you're looking for is software providing DLNA **Media Renderer** service as opposed to Media Server. There exist implementations for Windows (though some of them are audio-only).